# how to print words in a different color from a list and then show it on a window in python?

Tags: python, psychopy

How to add color to each word in a list in python and then print it into a window?

My code is this:

```
cognitivo = ["Plan","Organize","Help","liquidate","solvency","Prioritize","work","business","achievements","Control"]
for stimulus in cognitivo:
    mens = visual.TextStim(win, text=stimulus)
    mens.draw()
    win.flip()
    #core.wait(1.0)
```

just copy the list and as it is printed with the for loop, not to copy all the code I did...Only prints in a color and what I want is that each word in a specific color...Please, can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier, what you probably want to do is create a dictionary for each trial that holds all trial-related info together in one object (e.g. the text and colour for a trial). That makes it very easy to loop through a list of such dictionaries and easily access the trial values. Look into the PsychoPy `TrialHandler` class, which will do all of this and more (including saving data).

But just to fit within your simple code snippet, try this:

```
cognitivo = ['Plan', 'Organize', 'Help', 'liquidate', 'solvency', 'Prioritize', 'work', 'business', 'achievements', 'Control']
# create some corresponding colours:
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'black'] * 2

# initialise the text stimulus just once:
mens = visual.TextStim(win, text = 'XXXXXX')

# loop through the stimuli:
for stimulus in cognitivo:
    # update the stimulus:
    mens.text = stimulus
    mens.color = colors.pop()

    # display for 1 second at 60 Hz:
    for frame in range(60)
        mens.draw()
        win.flip()
```

Note that in general you shouldn't keep re-creating stimuli. Generally, just initialise it once, and then update its attributes. Creating a stimulus usually takes much longer than updating an existing one.

Comment: thank you very much, it was very helpful, i will check about the Trialhandler class